# Symfony 2 Collection Field returns "spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given"

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to build a multiphoto upload form. I followed http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html guide. However when I try to persist, I get this error

```
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in 
C:\htdocs\smileflame\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 1367
```

Could please someone check I am doing wrong? Here is my complete code: https://gist.github.com/dextervip/5650548

Comment: can you append your ItemType form please ?

Comment: please add the photo entity aswell

Comment: is there a particular reason you want many-to-many collection if many-to-one would be enough? and do you really need a jointable? will several items have the same photo, not likely if they are uploaded?  sounds somehow strange to me - please clarify. either way i'll update my answer a bit.

Comment: @nifr Well I have done reverse enginnering on the database, doctrine has generated it. I just want to add many photos to one product. Yeah many to one is enough! I didn't notice it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30634/discussion-between-nifr-and-dextervip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- mappedBy is NEVER the owning side of a doctrine relation.
- ManyToOne is always the owning side and the side which holds the JoinColumn definition
- You may aswell add cascade persist to have your Photo entities stored automatically when the Item is persistsed and you flush.
- Furthermore add the fetch EAGER option to automatically load the Image with the Item.

Implement those as follows add the this use statement:

```
use Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection
```

change property name to photos and change annotation:

**Item** ( *owning side* )

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\BX\AppBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="item", cascade={"persist","remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $photos;

public function getPhotos()
{
    return $this->photos;
}

public function addPhoto(PhotoInterface $photo)
{
    if (!$this->photos->contains($photo)) {
         $this->photos->add($photo);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function setPhotos(Collection $photos)
{
     $this->photos = $photos;

     return $this;
}
```

**Photo** ( *inverse side* )

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity=""\BX\AppBundle\Entity\Item" inversedBy="photos")
 * @JoinColumn(name="item", referencedColumnName="id_item")
 */
protected $item;
```